# Module exist in 'pip list' but i cannot import it

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-requests, python-import

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbeLh.jpg)

is screenshot of my problem, this server is in my uni so I don't have all the access, however I can see the package i want to install but get an error that says no module, i searched the web for a while but couldn't find a solution, how can I get it to work?

Comment: Install your packages with python3 -m pip install requests or pip3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
pip --version
```

Probably this is the Python 2.7 pip, and you are trying to use Python 3.
Check if `requests` is listed by:

```
pip3 list
```